# Ionic: button that unchecks all checkboxes

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a checkbox list setup that will add the selected items into an array which sends it to a service. I have a button that runs a function that empties the array on click, but the checkboxes remain checked.

[Here I select items and the red X appears, clicking that will clear the array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFFXH.png)

[Here is after I click the X, the array clears, but the items remain checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPHf.png)

**page.ts**

```
    if (this.checkedItems.includes(item)) {
      this.checkedItems = this.checkedItems.filter((value) => value != item);
    } else {
      this.checkedItems.push(item)
    }
    console.log(this.checkedItems);
  }
  createRoutine() {
    this.workoutService.selectedWorkouts = this.checkedItems;
    console.log(this.checkedItems);
  }
  uncheckAll(){
    this.checkedItems = [];
  }
```

**page.html**

```html
<div>
    <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm" animated="true"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list class="accordion-list">
      <ion-card size="full" >
        <ion-card-header> 
          <ion-item class="workout-title">            
            <ion-card-title> Workouts</ion-card-title>
            <a slot="end"><ion-icon name="close-outline" size="large" color="bic" *ngIf="checkedItems.length > 0" (click)="uncheckAll()"></ion-icon></a>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-card-header>
         <ion-card-content>
          <ion-list *ngFor="let workout of bic | filter:filterTerm | orderBy:'asc':'muscle'; let i = index;" class="workout-list" >    
            <ion-item>
              <ion-label>{{workout.name}}</ion-label>
              <ion-note>{{workout.muscle}}</ion-note>
              <ion-checkbox slot="end" color="bic" (ionChange)="onChange(workout)"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>   
          </ion-list>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

So I'm looking for a solution on how to have the `uncheckAll()` event uncheck the checkboxes after clearing the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `[(ngModel)]` for the check box, that will hold the checked status of check box. This should be bounded with the `workout` node.

We can mark it as `[(ngModel)]="workout.isSelected"` for example.

Inside `uncheckAll` loop through the array of `bic` and set the `isSelected` of each node as `false`

**Pseudo Codes**

*Template*

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let workout of bic | filter:filterTerm | orderBy:'asc':'muscle'; let i = index;" class="workout-list">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{workout.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-note>{{workout.muscle}}</ion-note>
        <ion-checkbox
            slot="end"
            color="bic"
            [(ngModel)]="workout.isSelected"
            (ionChange)="onChange(workout)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

*Component.ts*

```
uncheckAll(){
    this.checkedItems = [];
    this.bic.forEach(node => node.isSelected = false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response! I had a feeling it had something to do with `[(ngModel)]` though I didn't know how to implement it. This solution worked to uncheck all the boxes that were checked, however, for whatever reason the array is no longer being emptied.

Comment: It doesn't for some reason, when I remove the `this.bic.forEach(node => node.isSelected = false);` it does. I even console.log'd it and the array still has all the items I selected.

Comment: It does not. It does remove the checks, but for some reason causes `this.checkedItems = [];` to not work.

Comment: It should have you tried to log `this.checkedItems` in console after assigning `this.checkedItems = [];`?

Comment: Yes, it shows the array as still being populated. What I'm guessing might be happening is that it is clearing the array, and then activating the items again as it unchecks them?

Edit: yep, just removed `this.checkedItems = [];` and tried again, and it unchecked them and cleared the array.

Comment: So if this fixes you issue, please approve this answer, happy to have an upvote aswell

Comment: I can't leave feedback until I have 15 rep apparently, but I did approve your answer. Thanks again!